# Scrapy request returns NotImplementedError

Tags: python, scrapy

My scrapy code doesn't work and I have don't understand why. I'm just starting out scraping so I don't really care which site at the moment. I know that the issue does not deal with the url I am selecting.

Here is my code :

```
import scrapy

class Twitter(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "twitter_following"
    start_urls = ['https://www.digitalocean.com']
```

Comment: Can you show more of the code that actually replicates the error you are getting? That code is not providing the error you are specifying.

Comment: Exactly what  anytime you provide a troubleshooting situation on  developer forum... You should know that we are a bunch of stickler types in the sense that you need to have a complete and detailed report on your issue, As far as the not implemented error,  this is raised when you have built your spider incorrectly because it is not being recognized....  Aside from the fact that you build the classroom because Shirley scrapy would have built it correctly when you use genspirs...etc. PLEASE UPDATE YOUR ANSWER>

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat so.py 
import scrapy

class Twitter(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "twitter_following"
    start_urls = ['https://www.digitalocean.com']

$ scrapy runspider so.py 
2017-07-17 14:55:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2017-07-17 14:55:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digitalocean.com> (referer: None)
2017-07-17 14:55:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.digitalocean.com> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy14/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2017-07-17 14:55:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-07-17 14:55:25 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 218,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 18321,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 17, 12, 55, 25, 20602),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 47943680,
 'memusage/startup': 47943680,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 17, 12, 55, 24, 131159)}
2017-07-17 14:55:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

You need to define a [`parse` callback](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse): this is the default callback when no callback is referenced in `Request` objects.

```
$ cat so.py 
import scrapy

class Twitter(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "twitter_following"
    start_urls = ['https://www.digitalocean.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.debug('callback "parse": got response %r' % response)
$ scrapy runspider so.py 
2017-07-17 14:58:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2017-07-17 14:58:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digitalocean.com> (referer: None)
2017-07-17 14:58:16 [twitter_following] DEBUG: callback "parse": got response <200 https://www.digitalocean.com>
2017-07-17 14:58:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-07-17 14:58:16 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 218,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 18321,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 17, 12, 58, 16, 482262),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 47771648,
 'memusage/startup': 47771648,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 17, 12, 58, 15, 609825)}
2017-07-17 14:58:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```